# proxmox zfs pool not importing

Tags: zfs, proxmox

Today I restarted my proxmox server which has a zfs pool for my data.

The zfs pool did not come back up after the restart and is not visible in the proxmox UI.

When I try importing the pool manually I get the following result:

```
zpool import beastpool
cannot import 'beastpool': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

I examined the pool by issuing the zpool import command, which gives the following result:

```
zpool import
   pool: beastpool
     id: 9071326892089082027
  state: ONLINE
 status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
        some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
 config:

        beastpool                   ONLINE
          raidz2-0                  ONLINE
            wwn-0x50014ee2096e763a  ONLINE
            wwn-0x5000c500a5bbca7a  ONLINE
            wwn-0x5000c500a5be7966  ONLINE
            wwn-0x5000c500a5bff727  ONLINE
            wwn-0x50014ee26724a07e  ONLINE
            wwn-0x50014ee211cf6f82  ONLINE
```

As far as I can tell the pool seems healthy and all drives are online. I've tried scrubbing the pool, but this is only possible after importing. Any guidance is appreciated...